# d3 scatterplot display data year-by-year

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

So, I am creating a scatter plot using d3.js v6. All the data values have a year attribute.  On click of a button, the plot should transition automatically to each year. So, if the data has years 2000, '01, '02.... the graph should initially plot the data of the year 2000, then should transition to '01 in the next frame, and so on.
I have seen some examples and questions, but I couldn't understand them or find a tutorial. It would be great if you could help me or lead me to some tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to build the chart for a single year first (e.g., https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_basic.html). You'll then want to either update the chart using some sort of event (e.g., mouse click) or perhaps simply remove the svg element that you're displaying the chart on and redraw everything.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did build the chart for a single year. But I want the chart to automatically transition to the next years without any events.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You can use a timer like setInterval or loop through these updates with a delay.